# Message details TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'symbol')

Tags: google-apps-script

The google scripts code goes through the text of google docs if it finds an image it will stop and ask the user if wants to delete it if the answer is yes another dialog will ask the user which symbol wants to use to change the image for this symbol. But always I am getting this kind of message: Message details
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'symbol')

```
function showSymbolPrompt() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SymbolPrompt')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(400);
  var dialog = DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My Dialog Title');
  return dialog;
}

function processForm(form) {
  var symbol = form.symbol;
  if (symbol) {
    return symbol;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function eraseContent() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var images = body.getImages();
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (showPrompt()) {
      var symbolDialog = showSymbolPrompt();
      var symbol = processForm(symbolDialog);
      if (symbol) {
        var parent = images[i].getParent();
        var index = parent.getChildIndex(images[i]);
        parent.insertText(index, symbol);
      }
      images[i].removeFromParent();
    }
  }
}

function showPrompt() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Delete Image',
    'Do you want to delete this image?',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  return result.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      input[type="radio"] {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <input type="radio" name="symbol" value="∀">∀<br>
      <input type="radio" name="symbol" value="∃">∃<br>
      <input type="radio" name="symbol" value="→">→<br>
      <input type="radio" name="symbol" value="↔">↔<br>
      <input type="radio" name="symbol" value="¬">¬<br>
      <input type="radio" name="symbol" value="∧">∧<br>
      <input type="radio" name="symbol" value="∨">∨<br>
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">OK</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeDialog).processForm(document.getElementById('myForm'));
      }
      
      function closeDialog(symbol) {
        if (google.script.host) {
          google.script.host.close(symbol);
        } else {
          console.log("Unable to close dialog: google.script.host is null.");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am try to change images for these symbols: ∨∧¬↔→∃∀

Comment: `DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog()` returns void so in `function showSymbolPrompt()` `return dialog;` is null.